# Reading in space seperated dataset in R for frequent items

Tags: r, file-io

I have a .txt file that consists of numbers separated by spaces.  Each row has a different amount of numbers in it.  I need to do market basket analysis on the data, however I can't seem to properly load the data (especially because there is a different number of items in each 'basket').  What is the best way to store the data so I can find the frequent items and then check for frequent items in each basket?

Example of data:

```
1 2 4 3 67 43 154
4 5 3 21 2
2 4 5 32 145
2 6 7 8 23 456 32 21 34 54
```

Comment: You can construct a matrix (user,product) with the number of products for the user in each cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to input with `readLines` and then use lapply to separate into numerics. Assume that is in a file named txt.txt:

```
   dat <- lapply( readLines("txt.txt"), function(Line) scan(text=Line) )
```

The reason I didn't suggest read.table with fill=TRUE (which would give yiu something similar to the otehr answer that has appeared is that the column stucture was not  needed. unless there was information encoded in the position of those numbers. I'm wondering whether the might be additional information encoded in the individual lines such as regions or stores or some other entity as the source of particular numbered items. This would be the reason for keeping it in a list structure with an uneven count. You can get a global enumerations just with table:

```
table( unlist(dat) )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  21  23  32  34  43  54  67 145 154 456 
  1   4   2   3   2   1   1   1   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: How would I extract which items in the table have a count greater than a certain threshold (for example 3)?

Comment: It depends on whether the line position matters. If you just want the number associated wtih items having higher counts then just `which(  table( unlist(dat) ) >= 3)` or `names( which(  table( unlist(dat) ) >= 3) )`. If you wanted the line positions then you might use lapply to get a listing by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_text = '1 2 4 3 67 43 154
                    4 5 3 21 2
                    2 4 5 32 145
                    2 6 7 8 23 456 32 21 34 54'



my_text2 <- strsplit(my_text, split = '\n') 

my_text2 <- lapply(my_text2, trimws)



my_text2           %>%  
do.call('rbind',.) %>%
t                  %>%  
as.data.frame()    %>% 
separate(V1, sep  = ' ',into = paste('col_', 1:10))

col_ 1 col_ 2 col_ 3 col_ 4 col_ 5 col_ 6 col_ 7 col_ 8 col_ 9 col_ 10
1      1      2      4      3     67     43    154   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
2      4      5      3     21      2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
3      2      4      5     32    145   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>
4      2      6      7      8     23    456     32     21     34      54
```